# How to solve warning problems?

Tags: c

I am trying to resolve  warning issues which is shown  as below :

```
warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement
```

Relevant code:

```
cdc(.....)
{
    //some statements
    ENTER_FUNC(CDC_TRKEY_FC,cdcType_t); //Showing warning in this line
    if(something)
    {
        if(..)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

If I remove `;` and adding the braces as below

```
ENTER_FUNC(CDC_TRKEY_FC,cdcType_t)
{
}
```

the warning is gone.

What does exactly it means? Is it behaving like an `if` statement?
Sorry, its confidential code, so I cant share entirely.

Comment: why do you even have `if` with empty body?

Comment: It seems as explicit and obvious as it can get. Could you explain more about what gives you a problem?

Comment: `if (cond) ; else do_something();` or even `if (cond) ; do_something();` are syntactically OK and might do what intended. However, the compiler authors probably suspected an error and spent a warning about this. To make your intention clearer (because you want to use this as placeholder for later extensions) follow the hint and use `{ }` instead of `;` after `if (cond)`.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].

Comment: @Scheff Would you mind if I pick that up to improve the answer? (giving credits of course)

Comment: @Yunnosch You are welcome. (I guess we "were on the same path" at the same time...) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Consider making an answer instead. They woudl go well next to each other. Yours as a slightly different, valid angle. I wouldn't mind opvoting it.

Comment: @jwdonahue: I disagree. Even the question appears a bit premature-ish, I think, its still a valid question. It has enough information in it.

Comment: You need to keep the `if();` part in your code quote to have the question make sense. It is now hidden behind what is probably a macro, `ENTER_FUNC(`. Please [edit] to expand that macro.

Comment: I suspect that `ENTER_FUNC(CDC_TRKEY_FC,cdcType_t)` is a macro with `if` inside. If in doubt compile with `gcc -E` to get the real source code (as seen by compiler). But, please, don't be shocked about the amount of expanded source code as the pre-processor expands `#include`s as well...

Comment: Note that "it is confidential code" is one of the main reasons for studyin gand applying the concept of a [mcve].

Comment: But why no warning is showing after removing ; and putting{ }

Comment: Editing a question with two upvoted answers, in a way that makes both of them seem inapplicable, is not very well appreciated. Please [edit] your question to somehow get the `if();` information back into this new version (and keep the appreciated additional info). Or please roll back to the version which still fits the answers. In the latter case you can create a new question to discuss the `ENTER_FUNC(` thing (a macro at a gues) and the problems it causes.

Comment: And greetings to the authors of `ENTER_FUNC` - macros hiding `if` statments are a great invitation to "shoot in your own foot". ;-)

Comment: Because it contains the `if();` you seem to somehow be well aware of.

Comment: You know the `if();` is there. Please do not hide it.

Comment: Please show the definition of `#define ENTER_FUNC(`. You can change or delete everything inside, apart from the flow control bits, e.g. `if`.

Comment: Imagine you forget the `;` - no warning anymore: `ENTER_FUNC(CDC_TRKEY_FC,cdcType_t) do_always_something_absolutely_necessary();`. What, if the hidden condition in `ENTER_FUNC` fails? Such code can cause you many (unpayed) extra hours...

Comment: Note in the edit from version 2 to 3, the question lost the essential information, that there is a `if();` involved. It changed this into a different question (or the same question with actually LESS information and practically NO relevant information). This question has lost helpfulness and clarity. Version 2 was actually better. Either make sure that the essential info gets added again, or rolling back to version 2 would improve it. Which I then will consider to do.

Comment: @Scheff I assume that you are with me. I will act on my own if necessary. But I would welcome your support or your advise to the contrary.

Comment: @Yunnosch If I understood correctly the "`if();` replaced with `if(){}`" information is "something the OP has found" (demonstrate research effort), not actually what is inside the code. (coincidentally it's probably also what the macro expands to)

Comment: @user202729 Thanks for joining. You provided a new angle. Give me a minute...

Comment: @user202729 Good point. I already edited my answer, will adapt the question, especially my part there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your code

```
if (/* condition */);
/* other code */
```

Then the other code will ALWAYS be executed.
You probably want the other code to only be executed if the condition is true.

In order to achieve that, you mainly have to delete the `;`.
It is widely considered to be best practice to be somewhat generous with the `{}`, i.e.

```
if (/* condition */)
{
    /* other code */
}
```

The fact that the warning does not occur after deleting the `;` in line
`ENTER_FUNC(CDC_TRKEY_FC,cdcType_t);` and replacing it with `{}`
can be explained if it is actually a macro which essentially expands (together with the `;` which is NOT part of the macro) to the `if();`, which earlier versions of your question were mentioning.
The replacement with `{}` then does exactly what the compiler wanted.

The ENTER_FUNC() is probably meant to be used like

```
ENTER_FUNC(CDC_TRKEY_FC,cdcType_t) /* delete this ; */
{ /* new {, followed by rest of your function code */
if(something)
    {
        if(..)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }
} /* new */
```

Please excuse that this answer more or less assumes that you made a mistake in your code. Compare the contribution by Scheff, which assumes (also plausibly) that actually you were acting to a more complex design and fully intentionally.

Comment: Note:  This answer (and the current version of the one by Scheff) refer to an earlier version of the question, which mentioned a `if();` construct.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
if (cond) ; else do_something();
```

or even

```
if (cond) ; do_something();
```

might be intended. May be, the `;` after `if (cond)` is a placeholder for something which shall be added later.

Inserting comments

```
if (cond) /** @todo */ ; else do_something();
```

or

```
if (cond) /** @todo */ ; /* and then always */ do_something();
```

would make it clear to the human reader but not for the compiler which ignores comments completely.

However, the compiler authors suspected high chance that the semicolon was unintendedly set (and can easily be overlooked). Hence, they spent a warning about this and gave a hint how to make the intention clear if there is one:

Use `{ }` instead `;` for intendedly empty then-body to come around this warning.

Sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int cond = 1;
  if (cond) /** @todo */ ; else printf("cond not met.\n");
  if (cond) /** @todo */ ; printf("cond checked.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
cond checked.
```

[<kbd>**Life demo on ideone**</kbd>](https://ideone.com/zdkub8)

The compiler used on ideone is stated as gcc 6.3.

I must admit that I didn't get the diagnostics of OP.

---

After the question was edited, the answer does not seem to match the question anymore. Hence, a little update:

The OP states that the

```
warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement
```

appears for this line of code:

```
ENTER_FUNC(CDC_TRKEY_FC,cdcType_t); //Showing warning in this line
```

It seems that the OP was not aware that `ENTER_FUNC` is (very likely) a macro with an `if` statement in its replacement text (something like `#define ENTER_FUNC(A,B) if (...)`). (This is the most imaginable scenario to get this warning for this code.)

Unfortunately, the OP is not willing to show how `ENTER_FUNC` is defined, nor to prepare an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the same behavior.

However, the technique to hide an `if` in a macro is even more questionable – I wouldn't recommend to do so. Imagine the following situation:

```
cdc(.....)
{
    //some statements
    ENTER_FUNC(CDC_TRKEY_FC,cdcType_t) // This time, the author forgot the ; or {}
    if(something)
    {
        if(..)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

The `if(something)` statement becomes now the body of the hidden `if` of the `ENTER_FUNC()` macro which is probably not intended but a bug. The application may now behave wrong in certain situations. By simply looking at the source code, this is probably hard to catch. Only, by single-step debugging and a bit luck, the error can be found.

(Another option would be to expand all macros and check the C code after replacement. C compilers provide usually a pre-process-only option which makes the result of pre-processing visible to human eyes. E.g. [`gcc -E`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options))

So, the author of `ENTER_FUNC` built a macro which

- causes a compiler warning if macro is used properly
- where the warning goes away if macros is used wrong.

IMHO, this is a not-so-lucky design.

Comment: Good answer. I just wonder whether the `; else` actually compiles. Did you try? Admittedly I did not.

Comment: @Yunnosch Actually, I'm quite sure but I must admit I didn't try. Give me a minute...

Comment: It does. `if(i); else printf("Bye");` prints `Bye` if `i` is set to `0`. If thats what you meant :-)

Comment: @WedaPashi Thanks for joining. It seems it is me needing to do some experimenting and learning. Thanks both of you for making me aware.

Comment: Nice test code, with an appropriate and deserved sting towards me. :-) Good style.

Comment: ideone suppresses diagnostics

Comment: @M.M Yepp, you are right. On coliru, I got `warning: this 'if' clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]` with `g++ -std=c++17` but I couldn't convince it to compile with `gcc -std=c11`. So, I won't add this to my answer...